# Can't execute a MySQL SELECT statement when inside CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to create a simple loop of SELECT statements in MySQL to reduce code.  I have started this using `CONCAT()` however this causes the procedure to stop/fail. For example (where k is a loop counter):

`CONCAT('SELECT (Child_', k, ' INTO @Age_Child_', k, ' FROM lookup_childage WHERE ModYear = ModYear_var LIMIT 1)');`

To diagnose the issue, I simply tried to place the SELECT statement (without concatenated loop variables) inside a string to then be executed.  While I could get this to work for simple statements it would not work for the following:

```
SET @queryString = CONCAT('SELECT Child_1 INTO @Age_Child_1 FROM lookup_childage WHERE ModYear = ModYear_var LIMIT 1');    
PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Does anyone know why the `@queryString` containing the `CONCAT()` statement will not be executed/cause the procedure to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr The statement you're trying to write has the form `SELECT(rest of statement) LIMIT 1`. It should have the form `SELECT rest of statement LIMIT 1`.

It looks like you want to create variable column names, ummm, because your `lookup_childage` table is denormalized. I guess that table has these columns.

```
  Child_1   INT
  Child_2   INT
  Child_3   INT
  Child_4   INT
```

It looks like you hope to get a `@queryString` value containing this sort of thing:

```
SELECT Child_4 INTO @Age_Child_4 FROM lookup_childage WHERE ModYear = ModYear_var LIMIT 1
```

Only the `4`s are variable.

So to get that string you want

```
 SELECT CONCAT('SELECT Child_', k,
               ' INTO @Age_Child_', k,
               ' FROM lookup_childage WHERE ModYear = ModYear_var LIMIT 1'
              )
    INTO @queryString;
```

Comment: Thank you @o-jones, the string you constructed is exactly what I am trying to achieve.  My only clarification is that for some reason I am unable to then execute this within the Procedure using the 'PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;' and 'EXECUTE stmt;'  Do you know why this may not be executing?